# psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL and pgAdminIII on my Ubuntu Karmic box.

I am able to use pgAdminIII successfully (i.e. connect/log on), however when I try to login to the server using the same username/pwd on the command line (using psql), I get the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Does anyone now how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This stackoverflow post worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664239/2110769

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Did you set the proper settings in pg_hba.conf?

See https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql how to do it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've spent hours on it! All I want to do is run psql commands in my terminal. What do I need to make the file look like to do this??

Comment: @SeanA you need something like 'sudo -u postgres psql'

Comment: Don't forget to ';' at the end of every statement on psql. Sounds silly but it happens hehe.

Comment: I had to change PEER to md5, since I wasn't the postgres user in linux. with md5 it lets anyone login as the postgres user so long as they provide the correct password. It also works if you set yourself as the postgres linux user first, like @JLarky says.

Comment: For those using rails, I had to set the the pg_hba.conf, and change 'ident' to 'password'. Changing it to trust did not work.

Comment: Why yes, I did read the fine manual, but it didn't help one bit. It does not mention the error, or how to fix it.

Comment: You must make sure about the host being used to connect. Nowadays, the "localhost" typically stands for ::::1 IPv6 and not 127.0.0.1 IPv4 anymore. So the `pg_hba.conf` rule for the IPv6 can be different from the IPv4. In my case, the IPv6 was using `ident` while the IPv4 was using `md5`, for example.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a question to an answer.

Answer (score 474):

The following steps work for a fresh install of postgres 9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. (Worked for postgres 9.3.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 too.)

By default, postgres creates a user named 'postgres'. We log in as her, and give her a password.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
\password
Enter password: ...
...
```

Logout of `psql` by typing `\q` or `ctrl+d`. Then we connect as 'postgres'. The `-h localhost` part **is important**: it tells the `psql` client that we wish to connect using a TCP connection (which is configured to use password authentication), and not by a PEER connection (which does not care about the password).

```
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

Comment: If you set `PGHOST=localhost` you don't need to specify the `-h` option every time. This also works with other `pg_*` commands such as `pg_dump`.

Comment: It does documented in here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/postgresql.html

Comment: This was needed to enable a Mediawiki install on Debian with PostgreSQL.

Comment: 2 years later, and I need to do this on a [Mac](https://gist.github.com/mx4492/bfa209dbb12c98fb0b3a) too.

Comment: get out of postgresql command line by typing `\q`. Then you will be able to type `psql -U postgres -h localhost` in the proper context of `$`

Comment: bad because there is a security issue, see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install

Comment: THANKS - I was totally confused because it was asking for my Windows login password. Once I specified the line above, it pointed to the right location and worked!

Answer (score 178):

Edit the file `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf` and replace `ident` or `peer` by either `md5` or `trust`, depending on whether you want it to ask for a password on your own computer or not.
Then reload the configuration file with:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```

Comment: one command restart postgresql: /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

Comment: Why a restart when a reload is all you need?

Comment: In this case: "/etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 reload"

Comment: this one here worked for me. Change from peer to md5 was enough.

Comment: There is nothing "pg" or "postgres" in /etc.  Guess they decided to change everything that works, again, and of course not even a shortcut for backwards compatability.

Comment: OK, I'm a postgresql noob, but I must report that only `restart` worked for me, not `reload`--- after changes to `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` (changing `peer` to `trust`).

Comment: Today standard UBUNTU LTS use `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` ... so, use FrankHeikens's link :-)

Comment: For mac 10.11, postgres 11.2 -> /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf. This is the answer from @Vivek (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025972/postgresql-how-to-find-pg-hba-conf-file-using-mac-os-x) This works for me.

Answer (score 134):

You're getting this error because you're failing client authentication. Based on the error message, you probably have the default postgres configuration, which sets client authentication method to "IDENT" for all PostgreSQL connections.

You should definitely read section [*19.1 Client Authentication*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/client-authentication.html) in the [PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/index.html) to better understand the authentication settings available (for each record in [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)), but here is the relevant snippet to help with the problem you're having (from the [version 9.5 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/index.html)):

> **trust**
>
> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that
>   can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any
>   PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any
>   other authentication. See Section 19.3.1 for details.
>
> **reject**
>
> Reject the connection unconditionally. This is useful for "filtering
>   out" certain hosts from a group, for example a reject line could block
>   a specific host from connecting, while a later line allows the
>   remaining hosts in a specific network to connect.
>
> **md5**
>
> Require the client to supply a double-MD5-hashed password for
>   authentication. See Section 19.3.2 for details.
>
> **password**
>
> Require the client to supply an unencrypted password for
>   authentication. Since the password is sent in clear text over the
>   network, this should not be used on untrusted networks. See Section
>   19.3.2 for details.
>
> **gss**
>
> Use GSSAPI to authenticate the user. This is only available for TCP/IP
>   connections. See Section 19.3.3 for details.
>
> **sspi**
>
> Use SSPI to authenticate the user. This is only available on Windows.
>   See Section 19.3.4 for details.
>
> **ident**
>
> Obtain the operating system user name of the client by contacting the
>   ident server on the client and check if it matches the requested
>   database user name. Ident authentication can only be used on TCP/IP
>   connections. When specified for local connections, peer authentication
>   will be used instead. See Section 19.3.5 for details.
>
> **peer**
>
> Obtain the client's operating system user name from the operating
>   system and check if it matches the requested database user name. This
>   is only available for local connections. See Section 19.3.6 for
>   details.
>
> **ldap**
>
> Authenticate using an LDAP server. See Section 19.3.7 for details.
>
> **radius**
>
> Authenticate using a RADIUS server. See Section 19.3.8 for details.
>
> **cert**
>
> Authenticate using SSL client certificates. See Section 19.3.9 for
>   details.
>
> **pam**
>
> Authenticate using the Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) service
>   provided by the operating system. See Section 19.3.10 for details.

So ... to solve the problem you're experiencing, you could do one of the following:

1. Change the authentication method(s) defined in your `pg_hba.conf`
   file to `trust`, `md5`, or `password` (depending on your security
   and simplicity needs) for the local connection records you have
   defined in there.
2. Update `pg_ident.conf` to map your operating system users to
   PostgreSQL users and grant them the corresponding access privileges,
   depending on your needs.
3. Leave the IDENT settings alone and create users in your database for
   each operating system user that you want to grant access to. If a
   user is already authenticated by the OS and logged in, PostgreSQL
   won't require further authentication and will grant access to that
   user based on whatever privileges (roles) are assigned to it in the
   database. This is the default configuration.

Note: The location of `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_ident.conf` is OS dependent.

Comment: For me, this is the best answer. When you know all these options you can easily tweak the conf. And especially when you are on Dev machine you can simply set 'ident' for all entries to avoid wasting your time. Thanks

Comment: This was helpful for me too. In my case the pg_hba.conf file was set to peer, I changed it to password. Note that from a vanilla install I also had to set a password for the postgres user, sudo su - postgres psql, \password set a password. Then launch a default connection from pdgadmin3 with username postgres and your password you set.

Comment: And where is that file found?  Granted, you may need to make a list, since there seems to be no consistency between versions.  I guess I'll just run find on '/' .

Comment: @JosephK the location of those files is OS dependent. On a CentOS or similar RHEL variants, it'll be in `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.

Comment: On Ubuntu-16.04 it's `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: As someone who is new to psql, this is a huge help and should be the accepted answer as it caters to various authentication methods

Answer (score 49):

Simply adding the `-h localhost` bit was all mine required to work

Comment: Do we know why this fixes it?

Comment: postgresql's defaults aren't set reasonably. They may have fixed it by now, I don't know. Obviously the default url should be `this_computer = 'http://localhost'`

Comment: so fully using "pg_dump -U postgres test -f test_1.sql -h localhost" command worked for me

Comment: If you don't include a hostname (via the `-h ...` option) then `psql` will, by default, attempt to connect over a Unix-domain socket in which case `psql` (or maybe the PostgreSQL cluster itself) queries your OS for your user name to use peer authentication, i.e. confirm that your user name matches the PostgreSQL user (role) you specify (which it very well might not). When you specify a hostname, `psql` will use TCP/IP to connect to the cluster.

Answer (score 22):

In case none of the above works for you:


I've done quite a few Postgres installations, but was flummoxed today on a RedHat 6.5 system (installing Postgres 9.3).  My typical hba.conf configuration that Aron shows above didn't work.  It turned out that my system was using IPV6, and ignoring the IPV4 configuration.  Adding the line:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

allowed me to login successfully.

Comment: Thanks Ethan.

I am running Fedora 20 and i have facing the same issue as by the OP.

After changing the IPV4 and IPV6 to password. The connection was successful.

Comment: You're very welcome.  So many times I've benefited from others posts when encountering a programming or system problem.  Glad I could give back a bit.

Comment: This saved my life on Fedora 32!

Comment: working on Fedora 37 

Answer (score 22):

For fedora26 and postgres9.6

First, log as user root then enter to psql by the following commands

```
$ su postgres
```

then

```
$ psql
```

in `psql` find location of hba_file ==> means `pg_hba.conf`

```
postgres=# show hba_file ; 
 hba_file  
--------------------------------------   
 /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf  
(1 row)
```

in file `pg_hba.conf` change user access to this

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

Answer (score 18):

In my case, solution here: (for people who concerned)
login to postgres:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'; # type your password here
```

regards

Answer (score 17):

## Hmmm ...

If you can connect with the username and password in pgAdminIII but you can't connect with `psql` then those two programs are probably connecting to the  database differently.

[If you're connecting to different databases, first try connecting to the same database. See below.]

From [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.3: psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html):

> If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to localhost on machines that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

If you're not running something like `psql ... -h host_name ...`, and you're running Ubuntu, `psql` should be connecting via a Unix-domain socket, so PostgreSQL probably isn't configured to allow one of the password authentication methods for the *postgres* user.

You can test this by running:

`sudo -u postgres psql`

If the above works, your server is probably configured to use *peer* authentication for local connections by the *postgres* user, i.e. asking the OS for your user name to confirm that you're *postgres*.

## So It's Probably Your *pg_hba.conf* File

The full path of the file will be something **like** */etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf*. You can view it by, e.g. `sudo cat /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf | more`.

If you're omitting the host name in your `psql` command, you should be able to connect if you add the following entry to your *pg_hba.conf* file:

```
# Connection type   Database   User       IP addresses   Method
local               all        postgres                  md5
```

[Commented lines in the *pg_hba.conf* file start with `#`.]

If you **are** including the host name in your `psql` command, add this entry instead:

```
# Connection type   Database   User       IP addresses   Method
host                all        postgres   127.0.0.1/32   md5
```

You need to put the entry before any other entries are matched for your connection via `psql`. If in doubt about where to put it, just put it before the first un-commented line.

### More about *pg_hba.conf*

From [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.3: The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) [bold emphasis mine]:

> The first record with a matching **connection type**, **client address**, **requested database**, and **user name** is used to perform authentication. There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no record matches, access is denied.

Note that records are **not** matched on authentication method. So, if your *pg_hba.conf* file contains the following entry:

```
# Connection type   Database   User       IP addresses   Method
local               all        postgres                  peer
```

Then you **won't** be able to connect via:

`psql -u postgres`

Unless one of these entries is in your *pg_hba.conf* file **above** the former entry:

```
# Connection type   Database   User       IP addresses   Method
local               all        postgres                  md5
local               all        postgres                  password   # Unencrypted!
local               all        all                       md5
local               all        all                       password   # Unencrypted!
```

Comment: late to the game, but, seriously, thanks for putting in the effort to explain things properly so that I understand!

Comment: I have this issue when starting up the docker container, there is no pg_hba.conf file on my ubuntu system but maybe it is in the docker image? Then why is it giving this error for me?

Comment: @Zaffer I'm not sure what you're asking but it doesn't seem like it's _necessarily_ related to this question. I'm also not sure SO (this site) is a good venue for you to get help with whatever your underlying issue is either. I created [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240617/discussion-between-kenny-evitt-and-zaffer) and added you to it if you want to discuss your issue in more detail.

Answer (score 17):

Out of all the answers above nothing worked for me. I had to manually change the users password in the database and it suddenly worked.

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "alter user produser with password 'produser';"
```

I used the following settings:

### pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password  
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

Connection is successful finally for the following command:

```
psql -U produser -d dbname -h localhost -W
```

Comment: Following this helped me out here, Joseph. Especially, the connection command at the end to help me test it. Also, I'd add a restart of Postgresql service in case anyone is wondering (but I get it that it's implied). Appreciate it much!

Answer (score 16):

You can set the environment variable `PGHOST=localhost`:

```
$ psql -U db_user db_name
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "db_user"

$ export PGHOST=localhost
$ psql -U db_user db_name

Password for user mfonline:
```

Answer (score 10):

I found that I had to install an identity server, that listens on port 113.

```
sudo apt-get install pidentd
sudo service postgresql restart
```

And then ident worked.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is still your pg_hba.conf file. This line: You can found this file in /etc/postgres/varion/main

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
Should be

local   all             postgres                                md5
```

These are brief descriptions of both options according to the official PostgreSQL docs on authentication methods.

Peer authentication

The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is only supported on local connections.

Password authentication

The password-based authentication methods are md5 and password. These methods operate similarly except for the way that the password is sent across the connection, namely MD5-hashed and clear-text respectively.

If you are at all concerned about password "sniffing" attacks then md5 is preferred. Plain password should always be avoided if possible. However, md5 cannot be used with the db_user_namespace feature. If the connection is protected by SSL encryption then password can be used safely (though SSL certificate authentication might be a better choice if one is depending on using SSL).

After altering this file, don't forget to restart your PostgreSQL server. If you're on Linux, that would be `sudo service postgresql restart.`

Answer (score 6):

my solution on PostgreSQL 9.3 on Mac OSX in bash shell was to use `sudo` to go into the data folder, and then append the necessary lines to the `pg_hba.conf` file to allow for all users to be trusted and be able to log in.  This is what I did:

```
# in bash_profile edit PGDATA environmental variable
open ~/.bash_profile

# append this line to bash_profile
export PGDATA="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data"

# reload bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# open pg_hba.conf in vim
sudo vi /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf

# append these two lines to the end of the pg_hba.conf file
local   all   all                  trust
host    all   all   127.0.0.1/32   trust

# can now login as user in bash
psql -d <db_name> -U <user_name> -W
```

Comment: This is fine for the development server, but I wouldn't recommend this for a production environment as you no longer need a password to connect to the database with these settings.

Answer (score 5):

I've spent more time solving this error that I care to admit.

The order of authentication configuration in pg_hba.conf is relevant in your case I think. The default configuration file includes several lines in a vanilla install. These defaults can match the conditions of your authentication attempts resulting in a failure to authenticate. It fails regardless of additional configuration added at the end of the .conf file.

To check which line of configuration is use make sure to look at the default log file for messages. You might see something like this

```
LOG:  could not connect to Ident server at address "127.0.0.1", port 113: Connection refused
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "acme" 
DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 82: "host     all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident"
```

It turns out this default line is causing the rejection.

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

try commenting it out.

Answer (score 4):

If you've done all this and it still doesn't work, check the expiry for that user:

[Postgres password authentication fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564644/postgres-password-authentication-fails)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and I fixed it in **pg_hba.conf** when removing all *ident* methods even for IP6 address (in spite I have only IP4 on machine).

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 password
host all all ::1/128 password
#for pgAdmin running at local network
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
```

Answer (score 4):

It related to configuration issue of PostgreSQL installation:

Configure # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD section in below mentioned conf file

Find and Edit /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf or based on your file location to update method(md5). Update entry in the file if not existing for your config by comparing as below:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Configure CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION section in below mentioned conf file

Find and Edit /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/postgresql.conf or based on your file location
Update Listen Address and Port

```
listen_addresses = '*' // # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
port = 5432 // Set port as 5432
```

Restart your PostgreSQL:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-10 # Update service name based on your installation
```

Answer (score 3):

One hack around this is to edit pg_hba.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

To temporarily

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                   trust
```

At this point you are done. For security, then go and

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

then go back and set pg_hba.conf back to

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                   md5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it on CentOS,you may need to reload postgres after making the above solutions:

```
systemctl restart postgresql-9.3.service
```

Comment: It's now just `postgresql`

Comment: @NeilChowdhury postgresql service still has got version in service name at least in linux systems. Run this command to see `systemctl status | grep postgres`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows if you dont want to edit pb_gba.conf ie leave the method to MD5(default), create a new user, by **running this query** in Query tool in PGadmin
**[image: PGadmin]**

```
CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'secret'
```

then in **cmd**

```
psql "dbname=Main_db host=127.0.0.1 user=admin password=secret port=5432
```

where dbname is your db in postgresql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issuse after following this: [PostgreSQL setup for Rails development in Ubuntu 12.04](http://linuxrails.blogspot.com/2012/06/postgresql-setup-for-rails-development.html)

I tried the other answers but all I had to do was in: **"config/database.yml"**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: (appname)_development
  pool: 5
  username: (username you granted appname database priviledges to)
  password:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall pdAdmin to resolve this issue

```
brew cask reinstall pgadmin4
```

Answer (score 0):

I provisioned the username and password via terraform in GCP SQL and the problem was the password was not set properly via terraform so though not a proper fix but just to figure out the exact cause.

I changed the password for the user from GCP console and that worked.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me :
http://tecadmin.net/fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/#

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             myapp_usr                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: This allows anyone from localhost to login as any user. This behavior is not mentioned anywhere in the link. And yes, the debian info pages contain the same thing.