# Postgresql creating database

Tags: postgresql

Well I installed the latest postgreql database on my Windows 7.

Now I'm trying to create a database via the psql.exe command line

When I open it, it says

```
psql: FATAL: database "Jansu" does not exist
```

So I read somewhere, that when no database is specified, it tried to find database with my username or something.

Anyways..how do i create a new database, when I can't access the commandline.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Read [psql syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html). You can specify database, user and other parameters. If it's a new installation, there should be a default database 'postgres', you can connect to that one.

```
 psql -U postgres postgres
```

(In Unix environments you might need to add `-h localhost` in order to force a TCP connection, otherwise it'd try to use Unix-domain sockets, which might not work for other than the `postgres` user. )

You can create databases from there, or from the command line with [createdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-createdb.html)

Comment: psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres @Cody http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913897/postgres-whats-the-difference-between-local-and-localhost-connection-type

Comment: If I may add, `psql -U postgres postgres -h localhost`

Comment: @Frankline : that should not be necessary in Windows