# What's the difference between "local" and "localhost" connection types in pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql, connection, localhost

This is the relevant part of my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

The pidentd service is running.

When I try to log onto ee1 (I assume, the default user is postgres) :

```
psql ee1
```

It says "peer authentication failed for user postgres"

1. Where have I configured `peer` authentication for "postgres" ? It's `ident`.
2. When I change the following line in `pg_hba.conf`:

   ```
   local   all             all                                 ident
   ```

   to

   ```
   local   all             all                                 md5
   ```

   it asks me for a password, and I am able to log in. Why is it that making changes to the local connection type, have effect on postgres user?

Answer (score 3):

`ident` authentication means that your OS user matches DB user. It is support only for TCP/IP connections as [relevant entry in docs states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT). If used with Unix socket, [Peer authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) method will be used instead.

Also, note, that default user is not `postgres`, but the one you're currently logged in with.

Comment: I am logged to my system with my own username, then why is it saying that "peer authentication failed for user 'postgres'"

Answer (score 2):

`local` is a connection type used in pg_hba.conf, while `localhost` is the network address for local loopback and translates to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`, or IPv6 `::1`.
I quote [the manual about `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> **local**
>
> This record matches connection attempts using Unix-domain sockets. Without a record of this type, Unix-domain socket connections are
>   disallowed.
>
> host
>
> This record matches connection attempts made using TCP/IP. host records match either SSL or non-SSL connection attempts.
>
> Note: Remote TCP/IP connections will not be possible unless the server is started with an appropriate value for the listen_addresses configuration parameter, since the default behavior is to listen for TCP/IP connections only on **the local loopback address localhost.**

For the [GUC* `listen_addresses`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES) in postgresql.conf, `localhost` also serves as setting:
<sub>* GUC: [Grand Unified Configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/config-setting.html)</sub>

> The default value is **localhost**, which allows only local TCP/IP "loopback" connections to be made.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: I specified md5 for the 'host' connection type (with loopback address).. and tried 'psql ee1' and it never asked me for a password, but when I specified md5 for the 'local' connection type, it started asking me for a password. Why is that ? How do I know whether I am using Unix sockets to access localhost or using TCP/IP to access localhost ?

Comment: @Daud: If you connect locally (for instance, with `psql` on the same machine) the settings for `host` in `pg_hba.conf` are ineffective and the settings for the `local` connection type are relevant. You are automatically using a Unix socket when you don't supply a network address in your connection (and therefore, connect locally).