# Connection refused (PGError) (postgresql and rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I keep getting this error when i try to run my localhost using "$rails s":

(Mac OSX 10.8.3)
(ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]) 
(Rails 3.2.11)
(psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.2 ) **installed with homebrew

I have been doing a lot of uninstalling postgresql and reinstalling so I have a hunch that there may be conflicting libraries somewhere...i just dont know where to start.

I had Postgresql 9.1 and 9.2 in the same folder and just moved 9.1 into the trash.

Here is the output when I run "rails s" in the terminal

```
Danny$ rails s
^[b=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': could        not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3642716200177086041__prepare__4186317719333288752__callbacks'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/Danny/Dropbox/programming/coding/f_app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Danny/Dropbox/programming/coding/f_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/Danny/Dropbox/programming/coding/f_app/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/Danny/Dropbox/programming/coding/f_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/Danny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Inicias con el $>docker-compose up

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error message is instrumental:

> ```
> could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
> ```

#### port

You may be trying to connect to the wrong port.
Standard port is **5432**. Check how (and whether at all) you started your postgres server:

```
postgres@db:~$ ps -auxww | grep ^postgres
... <stripped more lines>
postgres  1274  0.0  0.3 1437240 57308 ?       S    May27   5:01 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

[The manual has related information here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-ps.html)

In my example, settings from `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` got used, which says (among many other settings):

```
port = 5432
```

**Or** run:

```
netstat -nlp | grep postgres
```

**Or** just look here (at least in Debian or Ubuntu):

```
ls -lA /var/run/postgresql/
```

PostgreSQL picks the next free port if you create a new database cluster. Since you installed repeatedly, you may have confused port numbers.

#### [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES)

Or you just [forgot to allow TCP/IP connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html#CLIENT-CONNECTION-PROBLEMS). Related answers:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)
- [What's the difference between "local" and "localhost" connection types in pg_hba.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913897/postgres-whats-the-difference-between-local-and-localhost-connection-type/11915567#11915567)
- [no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

Answer (score 5):

This may resolve the issue :-

- Get the hba.conf file address by using command `SHOW config_file;` and `SHOW hba_file;` in sql prompt
- Now open `hba.conf` and add this `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust`
- Now open `postgresql.conf` and add `listen_address = '*'`

Comment: `unrecognized configuration parameter "listen_address" in file "/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" line 59`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was caused by the upgrade of postgresql-9.4 to postgresql-9.5 in Ubuntu 16.04. Since, There were two versions installed at some point in time, the later installed version i.e. postgresql-9.5's config changed to default port of `5433` (instead of standard default `5432`).

The problem occurred when my Rails project tried to connect to the default port of postgresql (since the port was not defined explicitly defined in `database.yml` file) and kept failing. Even after removal of postgresql-9.4 later.

#### Solution changing postgresql's config file

The solution is changing the port in the configuration of updated postgresql (9.5). To do this open the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` and change the line

```
port = 5433                             # (change requires restart)
```

to

```
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

and then restart the server with `sudo service postgresql restart`.

#### Solution with changing Rails' `database.yml' file

Alternatively, you can change rails' `database.yml` file by explicitly mention the new port (that ie `5433`) without changing the postgresql's config file. To do this, simply add a line like this

```
port: 5433
```

and restart the rails server.

Comment: This was especially useful to know that database.yml defaults to port 5432 with rails. Also great explanation on why the port numbers were different for multiple versions of postgres

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main stop
```

followed by

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main restart
```

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message hooking up to Jira (from the Jira side) and the solution was to change the "Hostname or IP address of the database server." to "localhost".  If you're running locally you can't just put in your local ip address.

Also the next issue for a local install is the password always fails even though that's correct because pg_hba.conf needs to be edited so the authentication method is "trust".

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql.conf, `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` :

1. change the `listen_addresses = 'localhost' to listen_addresses = '*'`
2. enable the default port as 5432, `port = 5432`

Also in pg_hba.conf, `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`,
try the authentication method as trust

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the serve is not running. Try starting it.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```