# connecting to PgAdmin locally from amazon EC2 postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an amazon ec2 ubuntu instance and installed postgres in it but unable to connect it. I have enabled security group HTTP(80), Postgres(5432) and ssh(22).

While connect in pgadmin following errors are thrown
Server doesn't listen

```
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "54.172.***.***" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Try to find the answer on your own or at least try - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830893/3961156

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection refused (PGError) (postgresql and rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904997/connection-refused-pgerror-postgresql-and-rails)