# Error Creating Application Context on Basic Spring-Boot-Data JPA Project

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, applicationcontext

I am trying to create a basic Spring-Boot project that only deals with @Entity annotated classes and a basic JpaRepository for those entities.

When I try to run a basic test for the basic configuration of the project I get the following exception through JUnit(Jupiter).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to load ApplicationContext for 
[MergedContextConfiguration@717a8a76 
    testClass = com.example.demo.PersistenceLayerApplicationTests, 
    locations = [], 
    classes = [com.example.demo.PersistenceLayerApplication], 
    contextInitializerClasses = [], 
    activeProfiles = [], 
    propertySourceLocations = [], 
    propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], 
    contextCustomizers = 
        [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@5fd4f8f5, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2f8dad04, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@44821a96, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@22e357dc, 
        org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@978fd0ca], 
        contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]


    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:41)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    ... 129 more
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('testcontainersVersion', "1.17.6")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${testcontainersVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here is the Spring Boot Application file(PersistencLayerApplication.java)

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PersistenceLayerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersistenceLayerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the @Entity class

```
package com.example.demo.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    protected PersonEntity() {}

    public PersonEntity(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = null;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Here is the Repository class

```
package com.example.demo.data.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.data.entity.PersonEntity;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
    
}
```

Here is my application.yaml file

```
#Deployment Options for Spring Data and PostgreSQL
#Not yet confirmed to be correct
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/datamodel"
    username: foo
    password: bar
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  sql:
    init:
      platform: postgres
```

And here is my test file

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class PersistenceLayerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I have also tried to use an @DataJpaTest annotated test class thinking that I didn't configure my database properly but that one failed with the same error.

Here is that test file...

```
package com.example.demo.data;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import com.example.demo.data.PersonJpaTest.DataSourceInitializer;
import com.example.demo.data.entity.PersonEntity;
import com.example.demo.data.repo.PersonRepository;

@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = DataSourceInitializer.class)
public class PersonJpaTest {

    @Autowired private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Container //
    static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> database = //
    new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2-alpine") //
        .withUsername("postgres");

    public static class DataSourceInitializer //
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer
            <ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.
            addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment( applicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + database.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.usernam=" + database.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + database.getPassword(),
                    "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop");
        }

    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        personRepository.saveAll(
                List.of(
                        new PersonEntity(
                                "Mike",
                                "Bolger"),
                        new PersonEntity(
                                "Paul",
                                "Corrigan"),
                        new PersonEntity(
                                "Brenda",
                                "Butler"),
                        new PersonEntity(
                                "Gerald",
                                "Ford"),
                        new PersonEntity(
                                "Joe",
                                "Craig")
                        ));
    }

    @Test
    void findAll() {
        List<PersonEntity> allPersons = personRepository.findAll();

        for(PersonEntity person : allPersons) {
            System.out.println(person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName());
        }
    }

}
```

I know that there is a problem with the auto-generated ApplicationContext but I cannot see what I have done wrong. The book that I copied the example code from is essentially the same.

I tried running the test through the H2 database and got the same error.

Here is the application.yaml I used for that test

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

And here is the build.gradle for the test.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('testcontainersVersion', "1.17.6")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    //runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    //runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    //testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${testcontainersVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Do I need to include the web components of Spring-Boot to be able to run the spring-Data components or can you run a JPA program in isolation?

Comment: The two differences between my project and the one from the book is that I am using gradle as the build tool and I did not include the "spring-boot-starter-web" artifact in my build script.

Comment: Error is complaining that it cannot connect "PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." so it isn't using the test configuration and database credentials you are trying to setup for the test. Check that your methods are really being called (initialize ?) and the test application.yaml is in the right spot for the test to pick it up as it is strange that it is complaining about the original application.yaml connection settings

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

You need to check if PostgreSQL is actually listening on localhost:5432.
Read the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825734/postgresql-connection-refused-check-that-the-hostname-and-port-are-correct-an) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904997/connection-refused-pgerror-postgresql-and-rails) for more info.