# Create Postgres database using batch file with [template],[encoding],[owner] and a .sql file

Tags: database, postgresql, batch-file, database-connection, ddl

I want to create a Postgres database using a batch file.  Now the normal way of doing this is the following:

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\createdb.exe" -U Myadmin MydatAbseName

This script above creates a database with the default database parameters.  However, I want to create a database with the following parameters, as follows:

```
   WITH OWNER = Myadmin 
   TEMPLATE = template0 
   ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'C'
   LC_CTYPE = 'C'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Please tell me how to create a database with the above parameters using Batch files.

Also let me know how to use a .sql file to do the same, like this command-line:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\createdb.exe" -U Myadmin -f C:\createDB.sql;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The client program `createdb` does not support all those options.
Create a file `db_create.sql`:

```
CREATE DATABASE MydatAbseName
   WITH OWNER myadmin 
   TEMPLATE template0
   ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII'
   TABLESPACE  pg_default
   LC_COLLATE  'C'
   LC_CTYPE  'C'
   CONNECTION LIMIT  -1;
```

Call it:

```
psql -U postgres postgres -f C:/path/to/db_create.sql
```

The trick here is to connect to the **default maintenance db "postgres"** and create the new database from there. I do it with the **default superuser** named "postgres" in my example.
`psql -f` executes the SQL commands in the given file.

You could also just execute a single command with `psql -c` (no file involved):

```
psql -U postgres postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE MydatAbseName WITH OWNER Myadmin
EMPLATE template ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII' TABLESPACE  pg_default LC_COLLATE  'C'
LC_CTYPE  C' CONNECTION LIMIT  -1"
```

More on creating a database in the fine manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-createdb.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html).
More on [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).

---

On Windows, it looks something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\verson_number\bin\psql.exe" -U user -f C:/path/to/db_create.sql postgres
```

The last "postgres" is the name of the default maintenance db.
If you want to use it in a batch file you have to answer a password prompt or connect with a user that is allowed access without providing a password. Basics in chapters [The Password File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) and [The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) of the manual. More here:

- [Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Comment: hello,
i tried both the methods ,but i could not get them to work somehow,
for the first method im getting message saying


C:\>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" psql -u nansis_admin  -f 'C:\
createDB.sql'
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "nansis_admin" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-f" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "'C:\createDB.sql'" ignored
Password for user -u:


after i enter the password, no database is created.

Comment: my .sql file has the following content

________________________________________

     CREATE DATABASE MydatAbseName
     WITH OWNER nansis_Admin
      TEMPLATE template
      ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII'
      TABLESPACE  pg_default
       LC_COLLATE  'C'
       LC_CTYPE  'C'
      CONNECTION LIMIT  -1;

__________________________________________--

for the second method,
the no database is being created,

please help




thanks for the quick reply though :)

Comment: @PresleyDias: you have `psql` twice in your command. Try: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" postgres -U nansis_admin -f 'C:\createDB.sql'`. Works only if user `nansis_admin` has the required privileges.

Comment: Hey
my bad:)

but i tried this
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" postgres -U nansis_admin -f 'C:\createDB.sql'


but still msg comes on execution of the bat file


C:\>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" postgres -U nansis_admin -f '
C:\createDB.sql'
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "nansis_admin" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-f" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "'C:\createDB.sql'" ignored
Password for user -U:



nansis_admin is the superuser

Comment: @PresleyDias: I added some more to my answer.

Comment: its still not working,
my batch file content.

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -U nansis_admin -f 'C:\createDB.sql' postgres


nansis_admin is the super user

Comment: and my .sql file content is

CREATE DATABASE MydatAbseName
   WITH OWNER nansis_Admin
   TEMPLATE template0
   ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII'
   TABLESPACE  pg_default
   LC_COLLATE  'C'
   LC_CTYPE  'C'
   CONNECTION LIMIT  -1;

Comment: ____
hello
Erwin Brandstetter

ur method works, but if i remove the qoutes for this (-f  C:\createDB.sql)

thanks u very much for your help

Comment: The batch file Content should be

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -U nansis_admin -f C:\createDB.sql postgres










                  and the .sql file content should be



CREATE DATABASE presley
   WITH OWNER nansis_Admin
   TEMPLATE template0
   ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII'
   TABLESPACE  pg_default
   LC_COLLATE  'C'
   LC_CTYPE  'C'
   CONNECTION LIMIT  -1;

Comment: @PresleyDias: Cool! :) I removed the single quotes from my example as per your feedback.

Comment: Brandstetter : how to prevent the batch file from asking for password?

Comment: @PresleyDias: added another answer to my answer.

Comment: Brandstetter: if i change the port postgres is asking for password for the user while creating the database from the batch file,
i cannot figure out how to add the -w --no-password parameter to 

can you give me full example of it like "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\verson_number\bin\psql.exe" -U user -f C:\path\to\db_create.sql postgres -w     _______?

Comment: @PresleyDias: different port means different DB cluster and different pg_hba.conf file. Have you set up password-less access for the user in question? The `-w` option to `psql` only suppresses the password prompt if the user has the privilege to connect without password.

Comment: Ok, the user in my case is the superuser so he has all the privileges,
so how to suppress the user password prompt for the diff port ?
meaning the whole syntax like this "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\verson_number\bin\psql.exe" -U user -p 5433 -f C:\path\to\db_create.sql postgres -w"

Comment: @PresleyDias: There is no such thing as "a different port". A different port means a different database cluster - with its own users and privileges.

Comment: ok
i may be saying it wrongly...on my system i want to install a fresh copy of postgreSQl 9.0, using a batch file   'C:\temp\Postgres9.0\postgresql-9.0.2-1-windows.exe --serverport '5432' --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount _admin --superpassword k,zii --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended ;   ____since postgres has been installed on port 5432....but if i install postgres on port 5435 , during the database creation using your answer above..its is asking for password,

Comment: For the same procedure above for a fresh install on port 5432 it doesnt ask for password during the database creation through batch file

Comment: Kenny Evitt's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres, solved my issue!