# Jboss 4.2.3 datasource can't connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jboss, datasource, fedora

I have a problem in a cloud server Fedora 16 x64. I've installed PostgreSQL 9.1 from YUM repositories and it works fine. I connect from my PC through VPN and i use PGAdmin III to manage it, i just change the parameter listen_addresses to assign value '*' to connect to it. And i've installed Jboss 4.2.3 and i put a datasource file in the deploy directory with an EAR that uses that datasource, the file is dipr-ds.xml and it has the next content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>sainvDatasource</jndi-name>
      <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/diprinventory</connection-url>
      <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>postgres</user-name>
      <password>postgres</password>
   </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

But when i restart Jboss to deploy the EAR and it tries to connect to the database i get errors related to connection and application errors, the application doesn't work but now i'm focusing in resolve the problem with the connection, to find out why the application can't connect to Jboss if it works fine when i manage from my machine using VPN. This is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authenticatio$
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:190)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:619)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:264)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:575)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:347)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:330)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:402)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:849)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
        ... 151 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:106)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:172)
        ... 159 more
2012-05-21 09:49:04,226 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] could not complete schema update
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "$
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:713)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:127)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:246)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceDelegateWrapper.startService(ServiceDelegateWrapper.java:103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceDelegateWrapper.startService(ServiceDelegateWrapper.java:103)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy70.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.JmxKernelAbstraction.install(JmxKernelAbstraction.java:120)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.startPersistenceUnits(Ejb3Deployment.java:627)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.start(Ejb3Deployment.java:351)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Module.startService(Ejb3Module.java:91)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy33.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.start(EJB3Deployer.java:512)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy34.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
                        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authenticatio$
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:190)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:619)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:264)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:575)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:347)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:330)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:402)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:849)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
        ... 151 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:106)
...
```

I don't know if is an issue related to Jboss or a configuration setting of PostgreSQL, so I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Postgres is trying to authenticate the user owning the calling process, that is the java process running JBoss. See for example:

[psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me using 'trust' in the configuration of pg_hba.conf . But why doesn't work if i use md5?