# Postgresql: How to find pg_hba.conf file using Mac OS X

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am having trouble with postgres. I don't remember my postgres password and don't know how to change the password. I'm guessing I should change the md5 password settings I set a month ago, but I don't know how to find the file and open it using my terminal. Can someone help?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Another way I learned recently is to go to the terminal and type:

`ps aux | grep postgres`

which shows all the postgres processes running on your machine. From the list you should see one with the format `... -D ...`. E.G:

```
root            4155   0.0  0.0  2432908     68   ??  S     6May13   0:00.01 sudo su postgres -c /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql84/defaultdb -p 5432
```

the -D means directory. In the terminal, do a `sudo su` and then cd to that directory, and you'll find the pg_hba.conf file.

And one more way:

Go to your terminal and type: `locate pg_hba.conf`. There should be a few results.

Comment: Thanks helpful .. [link](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2009/06/postgresql-how-to-reset-user-name.html) for future..

Comment: In latest Postgres 9.x it will be found in /data/ directory
like /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf

Comment: In my MacBook Air 11.2.3 (2020) - Postgres 10
/Library/PostgreSQL/10/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample

Answer (score 87):

If you can connect, use `SHOW hba_file;`.

If you cannot connect, you need to locate the data directory. That'll be shown as the `-D` argument to the `postgres` or `pg_ctl` command that starts PostgreSQL, so you can generally find it with `ps -ef | grep postgres`.

Comment: Example result on my Mountain Lion Mac with Postgres 9.2 installed by EnterpriseDB.com installer: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: For mac 10.11, postgres 11.2 -> /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque I found the data directory but cannot access that. Error of having no permission to read data content prompted.

Comment: @SharkDeng For enhanced security, that directory is controlled by the user account created on your system when you installed Postgres. That user is likely called `postgres` unless you specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS 12, you can open the file using nano in your terminal. Example below is if Postgres 12 is installed.

```
`nano /Library/PostgreSQL/12/data/pg_hba.conf`
```

Comment: Different user can have different paths, find yours like this: 
sudo psql -U postgres -c 'show hba_file'