# PostgreSQL user authentification error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL for my Rails application. The authentification to the PostgreSQL server via pgAdmin and console is successful, but when I run Rails application I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

My `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_dating
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: '123456'
```

The `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I use Rails 4.0.1 and PotgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pg_hba.conf` you posted appears to not be complete. You probably have another entry similar to this in it (probably a bit more to the top):

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

The Postgres [documentation for the pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) state regarding peer authentication:

> *peer*
>   Obtain the client's operating system user name from the operating system and check if it matches the requested database user name. This is only available for local connections. See Section [19.3.7](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) for details.

Thus, you have to make sure, that you use the local unix socket (not a TCP connection) with this configuration. Also, you need to have a `postgres` user in your Postgres database.

An alternative would be to instead remove that line from the `pg_hba.conf` to fallback to the other mechanisms defined. Make sure that your `postgres` user has a valid password set though.

Note that is is common to have a predefined superuser named `postgres` which has all the rights without any permission checks. It is not wise to use that user for applications (e.g. your Rails app). instead, create a new dadicated user in your Postgres database and use that one for your app.