# PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, authentication

When I attempt to run "rake test" on a local postgres database, it throws the above exception.

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                peer

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             username                                  peer
local   myapp_dev   myapp                               md5
local   myapp_test  myapp                               md5
local   myapp_prod  myapp                               md5
#local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

and here is the relevant section from my database.yml

```
test:

adapter: postgresql
database: myapp_test
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
host: localhost
username: username
password:
```

In the real database.yml, 'username' is replaced with my actual user name that I am logged in as.  Since the authentication method is defined as 'peer', no password should be required.

I have also taken care to restart Postgres

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main restart
```

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`localhost` as a host refers to a TCP connection, which means the auth method is `md5` (password required) per your `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

For the `peer` method to be taken, you'd need to connect through Unix domain sockets, and since you seem to be using a debian-like OS, that means putting `/var/run/postgresql` in the `host` field, or nothing at all (it's the default unless environment variables say otherwise).

EDIT: if using database URIs (supported since Rails-4.1, as announced in
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/), the syntax could be:

- for localhost:
  `test: "postgresql://localhost/myapp_test"`
- for the default Unix socket domain (host field left empty):
  `test: "postgresql:///myapp_test"`

Comment: Please note that **host field** refers to ```host: localhost``` in database.yml, I used ```host: /var/run/postgresql``` and it works as well. Thanks for answering! (under Debian 7.8)

Comment: When you say "nothing at all", do you mean `host: ""` or removing the `host` key completely?

Comment: @Dennis: good question, I was answering from a postgresql perspective, but in terms of syntax in database.yml and if/how empty fields are to be submitted, I don't have the answer. If you or someone else are inclined in testing it, feel free to edit the answer with the results.

Comment: @DanielVérité I removed `host` and didn't notice issues, and @Isiden had success with `host: ""` so my guess is both work. I didn't it look into it much so I feel safer leaving this comment instead of editing the answer.

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` file is located on the `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` on Ubuntu

Comment: When using `postgres://` style URIs, replacing `postgres://localhost/database` by `postgres:///database` does the trick.

Answer (score 33):

Change the code as below and it will work

```
pg_hba.conf:
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Below its explanation:

> trust
>
> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that
>   can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any
>   PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any
>   other authentication.
>
> md5
>
> Require the client to supply a double-MD5-hashed password for
>   authentication.

refer for more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21166595/2640303)

Comment: It actually worked for me. But could someone elaborate on if it rather secure or not? Does it mean, that all connections omit the password from now on?

Comment: That means all connections from any local user are [allowed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-trust.html) without password or any other sort of authentication. "When trust authentication is specified, PostgreSQL assumes that anyone who can connect to the server is authorized to access the database with whatever database user name they specify (even superuser names)." I'd rather choose the [`peer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-peer.html) method: "...works by obtaining the client's operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed database user name..."

Answer (score 11):

If your hb_conf has already been modified to force passwords, then make sure your rails app's database configuration includes a password in both development and test environments.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: your_user
  password: your_password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: your_db_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: your_db_test

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I was getting this error when I failed to supply a password for the test database.

Answer (score 0):

I use Postgres App. Which is really great because you don't have to supply username and password in the default part of the database.yml

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my-app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my-app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my-app_production
  username: my-app
  password: <%= ENV['MY-APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**My problem**: I changed the path and wasn't able to get postgres to work.

**Solution**: use the [documentation](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html) to:

1) Uninstall the app

2) Stop the postgres process using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416527/postgres-app-port-in-use?rq=1), which says to use `sudo pkill -u postgres`

3) Reinstall and start the app

Everything should work fine now, have a great day!

**Note**: Doing this also solves the problem *Postgres.app port 5432 in use*

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, solved by a coworker:
You need to set a local user and password in postgres

```
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
```

It will ask you for the name of the role (the user) and the password you want to have.

Then you have to add this username and password to your database.yml file

Answer (score 0):

rename method from `peer` to `trust` in `/etc/postgresql/<postgres-version>/main/pg_hba.conf` file.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 0):

**initialize dot environment in your project**

```
   # dot gem
 gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
```

than `bundle install`

and than make a .env file in your project and add the following line

```
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_USER= user_name
POSTGRES_PASSWORD= your_password
RAILS_MAX_THREADS=5
```

Answer (score -1):

I met this question, too. I checked my database config, `/var/www/myproject/shared/config/database.yml`:

```
production: 
adapter: postgresql 
pool: 5 
timeout: 5000 
encoding: utf8 
host: localhost 
database: myproject
username: myname 
password: <%= ENV['name_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I found the last paragraph is wrong, the right code is

```
password: <%= ENV['myproject_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```