# Rails console no password supply error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am running a rails application with postgresql as a database, 
I have a user on the database with empty password.
The application runs successfully but when I am trying to 
use a model from the console I am getting the following error.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you are doing when you "use a model from the console"?  Eg the actual code you are typing or whatever.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 33):

Short answer, in your `database.yml` file, replace:

`host: localhost` with `host: ''`

This should do the trick.

For long answer and explanation, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375740/pgconnectionbad-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied)

Comment: This will likely cause a problem with various CI environments. I get around that by doing this `host: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>`. Then set the `MYAPP_DATABASE_HOST` environment variable on your development machine `MYAPP_DATABASE_HOST=""`. Do not set this envar in production or in CI.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: It also returns `Caused by: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`. By default the superuser postgres has no password I shouldnt have to change `peer` to `md5` in `pg_hba.conf`