# Postgres.app port in use

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am trying to start the server and getting an error

```
Port 5432 is already in use
```

I have brew uninstall postgress

```
which postgres
```

gives me nothing.

Activity monitor has 14 postgres processes which I cannot kill.
Force quit kill the process and restarts it with another pid.
The same with 
    `sudo kill -9 PID`
it kills the process and restarts it with another PID.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you checked for a launch daemon? It controls the Postgres process when Postgres is installed with Homebrew, and it automatically restarts Postgres after it is killed. Try

```
sudo launchctl list
```

or

```
sudo launchctl list | fgrep postg
```

to find the name of the daemon. You can stop the daemon with `sudo launchctl stop <name>` where `name` depends on the result of the first command.

Answer (score 28):

If you are running into this problem on OSX, do the following:

1. Find out what is running on that port:

```
    $ lsof -n -i4TCP:5432

    COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    python2.7 28687 afdasdfasd    3u  IPv4 0x2f18e1284963d3e3      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:54970->127.0.0.1:postgresql (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

2. Kill it

```
    $ kill -9 28687
```

3. Restart postgresapp

Comment: The command `lsof -n -i4TCP:5432` did the trick for me, "netstat" didn't yield anything for port 5432 on OSX. Thanks!

Comment: This one worked for me as well. In my case, I found out I was using DataGrip, and it seems it kept the port in use even when PostgreSQL was not running anymore.

Answer (score 18):

Askubuntu provided an answer that worked:

```
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

Source: [Nicely stop all postgres processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547434/how-to-nicely-stop-all-postgres-processes)

Comment: The OP runs Postgres under MacOS (the _Activity Manager_ is a very subtle hint for that) from the Homebrew package. Homebrew uses `launchctl` to start and stop Postgres. If you stop Postgres with `kill`, it will be restarted by `launchctl`. The OP has already tried your solution without luck.

Comment: Alright, but I came to this question because I needed an answer and there is no explicit mention of homebrew. So for others that come to this question, my solution may be a better fit.

Answer (score 11):

`$ brew services stop postgresql`

This will kill all processes and let you start the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of ports using:

```
sudo launchctl list
```

Then enter the application name, and using this command to get the port nunber:

```
sudo launchctl list | fgrep postg
```

In my case, the port is 83. Now use:

```
kill 83
```

then

```
sudo kill 5432
```

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands

- To check what is running on port 5432 - **$ sudo lsof -i :5432**
- To kill Postgres - **$ sudo pkill -u postgres**

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

Good luck!

Comment: This solution is already provided in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52958226/5320906).  When answering old questions please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.