# Django localhost default port already in use with postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

I am receiving a error when running postgres, pgadmin and django.
Port is already in use. I know how to use the sudo command to kill the server, however I am not being shown my databases in postgres. It just shows running when I start the server. When I create a new port database shows but doesn't migration the data. Also when I run migrations to django I get error, table already exist and or table doesn't exist. This happens everytime as if there is a duplicate database and it's not connected to the one showing in pgadmin. I tried dropping and deleting tables in pgadmin, and still get table exist.
How do i fix this? How do I show all databases connected and delete the one that overrides my default port and have postgres show database servers in the app.
Thank you in advance. Long post but I'm stressing and cant find a solution.

Deleting tables in pgadmin, change port number, open postgres first than start pgadmin.

Comment: you can try kill whatever use port, and run again. 
If you use port 5432. Like this below
`lsof -ti:5432 | xargs kill -9`

Comment: May be it's your solution link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418060/19205926)