# configuration of postgresql in Django project

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to configure the postgresql in django project, here is my settings

```
DATABASES = {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'NAME': 'newdb',
             'USER': 'vishnu',
             'PASSWORD': 'dsvv',
             'HOST': 'localhost',
             'PORT': '',
         }
    }
```

when I run syncdb command it gives the error "OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "vishnu"". I tried the answers given in this link 
"[psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)" as well several other links but its still giving me the error.

what is the problem how can I fix it?

Comment: edit the pg_hba.conf file .. give `trust` to all connection

Comment: @rajasimon bad idea. very insecure. set a password for the desired users then switch back md5 authentication.

Comment: thanks for concerning my question. I already used trust as well as md5 but still getting same error; after that only i posted the question.