# Postgres will not allow alter role superuser and my default user isn't superuser

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, psql, pg-hba.conf

I cannot connect to Postgres using Elixir:

```
** (Mix) The database for PhoenixChat.Repo couldn't be created: FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password): password authentication failed for user "postgres"

00:08:59.053 [error] GenServer #PID<0.3214.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password): password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

I cannot understand how a database could allow users to be made without one being a superuser. From my usual user, it does not allow giving superuser role:

```
$ psql -U thisone --password
Password for user thisone: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "thisone"

$ psql -U fakeuser
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "fakeuser"

cchilders=> alter user postgres superuser;
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
cchilders=> select rolname from pg_roles;
  rolname  
-----------
 postgres
 cchilders
 fakeuser
 thisone
(4 rows)

$ psql -U postgres --password
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How can I give a user superuser in Postgres if there is no superuser?

Comment: there's no other passwords except what I've tried. should I reinstall

Comment: Correct answer `sudo -u postgres psql` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "thisone"` and same error for other user means, you try to connect on socket with different os user (eg. os user is `cchilders` and you try `psql -U postgres`), while `peer` m[eans you have to be logged in same OS user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html). For example, to success in `psql -U thisone` you should before `sudo su - thisone`. If you dont have such OS user, you cant connect with `peer` authentication. So either change in **hba_file** `peer` to `trust` for passwordless or `md5` for password auth to postgres not being same os user...

For you `sudo -u postgres psql` worked, because you have os user postgres (which is not the case with osx for example)..

And lastly, you list users, not checking if they are superusers. You should either `\du` metacommand with `psql, or add`rolsuper` column, so it would be:

```
select rolname from pg_roles where rolsuper;
```