# How to allow postgres login without password prompt on local connection?

Tags: postgresql

How do you configure PostgreSQL to allow the default postgres user to login without a password from localhost?

There are several similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres), but none of the suggestions to modify `pg_hba.conf` have worked for me. However, based on my understanding of the `pg_hba.conf` rules, I should be able to accomplish this with either the `peer` or `trust` options.

I'm trying to run a command like:

```
sudo psql --user=postgres --no-password --command="blah;" -h 127.0.0.1
```

If I try this line in my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

my command fails with the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

If I tried this line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

my command fails with the same error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you specify `-h 127.0.0.1` that is **not** a "local" connection - it's a host (=TCP based) connection. So a line starting with `local` will not match for such a connection.

To make that entry work, do **not** specify a hostname or port for `psql`, then it will use a "local" connection through named pipes.

Alternatively, you can `local` with `host` and then add `127.0.0.1` as the (client) IP address to "trust".

Comment: Sorry I am newbie to postgres, please share the complete psql command.