# How to connect postgresql using php on centos

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I tried to test connection using php and database postgresql using below codes:
But I got message error like this:

**pg_connect(): Unable to connect to postgreSQL server: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"**

```
<?php
     $connect = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypass");
     if(!$connect)
     {
         $error = error_get_last();
         echo $error['message'];
     }
     else
     {
        echo "Connected";
     }
?>
```

can someone help me please. btw I Using Centos 7.2

Comment: Can you connect to the database with a tool (f.e. cmd line, pgadmin)?

Comment: Hi @manuzi1 Thanks for replied, sure I can connect using command. And I also I have added password using this :  \password postgres

Comment: Try to check out this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres