# How do I connect from R to Postgres without getting: "FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user..."?

Tags: postgresql, shiny-server, rpostgresql

I have an R shiny server which also hosts a PostgreSQL Database. However, I have trouble connecting R with Postgres.

Here is my R script:

```
library("dplyr")
library("RPostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname = "___", host="localhost", port="___", user="___", password="___")
```

With  `Rscript "skript.R"` I get this error:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect _____@localhost:___ on dbname "versuch1": FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "_____"
)
Calls: dbConnect -> dbConnect -> postgresqlNewConnection -> .Call
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong. Any hints?

Comment: Are you able to connect through a different client using those credentials?

Comment: There's a  question with answers on that error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Comment: @JNevill How do I connect through a different client?

Comment: Perhaps check out that link that @mlinth suggested first. If that doesn't pan out then I was suggesting that you connect to your postgres database through another client besides R to test connectivity for the username/pass you ahve set up on your database. If you are on the linux command line you can use `psql` client, for instance.