# Reposting - Error: Ident authentication failed for user

Tags: node.js, postgresql, centos

I feel like the foot traffic is slow on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533896/error-ident-authentication-failed-for-user), so I'm also posting this question here:

I have a Postgres installed in CentOS, along with Node and React with NGINX.  I've left alone my Unix `postgres` account to be without a password as recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install).  I've also written migrations with postgrator, which creates a table as `blog_user` in the `blog_database`.

My `blog_user` has `LOGIN` attribute with encrypted password, and the database `blog_database` is owned by `postgres`.

When I run my migrations in CentOS, I get this message

```sh
[joseph@vultr backend]$ yarn run migrate
yarn run v1.17.3
$ postgrator --config postgrator-config.js
[2:41:39 AM] table schemaversion does not exist - creating it.
[2:41:39 AM] version of database is: 0
[2:41:39 AM] migrating up to 2
Error: Ident authentication failed for user "blog_user"
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When attempting to change `peer` to `md5` for `all`, I am required to put in a password for `postgres`

```sh
-bash-4.2$ vim /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf 
-bash-4.2$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
```

Executing the restart command as root leads to this message

```sh
[root@vultr ~]# vim /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf 
[root@vultr ~]# systemctl restart postgresql.service
Failed to restart postgresql.service: Unit not found.
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to solve this.

Comment: I feel with you that your question has not been answered, but that does not override the sire rules, namely „Ask questions about specific _programming_ problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, software development tools.“ As a general advice, while I like vultr - if you are not an experienced system administrator (which - sorry - apparently you are not): Do not reinvent the wheel and make your life (much) easier by using some service. For example, you can have a Postgres cluster running [on DO](https://m.do.co/c/40f88d7ea4f0) complete with a standby node for as little as $50/month.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you for your advice.  I appreciate it.  I am up for the challenge though, and it is ok to beat me down with lots of technicalities, I'll learn it.

Comment: That is hardly the point. Without supervision, you might make a critical mistake. Which, in the best case, simply blows up something. In the worst case scenario, you leak data. Which, in some jurisdictions, makes you personally liable - including, but not limited to, damages and compensation. If you really have to, I suggest using docker on CentOS with (!) fail2ban(!). AND learn how to properly update your application stack with it _before_ going live. That should give you a halfway decent setup and basic security.

Comment: As a starter: I created a [role for ansible which configures an openssh server to be properly secured](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/ansible-role-sssh) (to the best of my knowledge and that of one expert I trust)

Comment: Hmm, I understand.  I'll definitely look more into those things, I have a little experience with docker, but I gave this linux setup a go for this project.  I've done some SELinux configuration on this server as well, which I felt like was off-topic for my question.  Can you give me some pointers about my problem? like user permissions or something that may be an issue.

Comment: I voted it to be off-topic, since it is not related to programming. Programmer‘s questions != programming questions. Your question is better suited for https://serverfault.com. And please refrain from double posting ;) If you post there, please delete here.

Comment: wait, but what about this well received question on stack overflow :( , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres?rq=1

Comment: The comparison might fall a bit short, but if one gets away with murder does not mean you want all murderers to get away with it, do you? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `trust` authentication for local connections unless you have untrusted operating system users on the machine.
2. The PostgreSQL service probably has a different name. Try

   ```
   systemctl status | grep postgres
   ```

Comment: I am able to confirm that setting to either trust or md5 works.  It turns out that finding the right service name was my main issue, sigh.  Thank you!