# psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

i installed and setup postgresql-12 with the commands from here [https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/]

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql12
yum install postgresql12-server
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/postgresql-12-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-12
systemctl start postgresql-12
```

i then tried to log into the database

```
psql postgres postgres
```

i got the error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

there are two pg_hba.conf files on my system. i checked the authentication settings, shown below, as recommended here [[psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres])

/data/pg_data_dir/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5  
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

the authentication settings look OK, so i'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: you need to reload the conf before you can use the updated `pg_hba.conf` file -- you can just restart postgres or `su - postgres` before trying `psql`.  Once you get into `psql`, issue `select pg_reload_conf();`

Comment: Your error message states that `peer` authentication failed. The `pg_hba.conf` files you show do not include rules using the `peer` authentication method. Are you sure there is no other `pg_hba.conf` file? Check the `hba_file` entry in your `postgresql.conf` file.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT - To make this more structured and usable.

First, you need to understand what each of those authentification methods mean, there is a ton on infromation in [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-methods.html) about this. Long story short, at this stage, the one you'll likely be interested in is `md5` which is a hashed password, or `trust` which is no password.

After installing the postgres on your machine, you'll need to become the `postgres` user and then attempt `psql`

```
~# su -l postgres --assume you're postgres
~$ psql --connect

psql (xx.x ))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Once you're in, you can set a new password for that user:

```
postgres=# \password postgres
```

To prevent this from happening, you'll need to ask postgres where the hba file is:

```
postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
```

Use your favourite text editor and modify it to fulfill your needs.

Also you need to make sure you reload the postgresql service, the command is:

`sudo systemctl reload postgresql-12.service`

Comment: psql -U postgres returns the same error even after restarting. thanks

Comment: can you try the following command: ```su -l postgres``` followed by ```psql```

Comment: psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: what about ```sudo -u postgres psql``` ? is this returning the same error?