# connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to set up Django PostgreSQL in Django application. I created the db, user and password for the user and when I run `\l` I can see the db. When I run the django app with `python manage.py runserver` i get the following error messages.

```
ON PURE START UP
USER TABLE NOT EXIST
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Server not found in Kerberos database
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

What am I missing

Comment: Since you say you created a password, presumably you want to use password based authentication, which ident is not.  So you need to change pg_hba.conf.

Comment: what do I need to change? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Or start the ident daemon.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres) answer your question?

Comment: I had to ask env vars from the team lead I now I got it working.